# Using chocolate for caramel instead of butter

Tags: caramel, caramelization, melting-chocolate, popcorn, melting-sugar

For caramel popcorn, what if we use a chocolate compound instead of butter for caramel. Even if it doesn't become caramel, can it be used for coating popcorn like caramel?

Please suggest me if there is any other cheaper way to make it like caramel by using chocolate (and oil if required).

Comment: are you wanting to do somethin like this https://www.thechunkychef.com/chocolate-covered-popcorn/ ?

Comment: If you mean you want to add the chocolate to the melted sugar instead of adding butter (and cream), my first thought is no. The sugar will be very hot, well above the burning point of the chocolate, and both texture and taste will be ruined.

Comment: @senschen : maybe you could stir in cocoa butter (or white chocolate), to cool it, and *then* stir in a really dark chocolate once the temperature's come down?